# Translating a powershell query to an AD filter

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to translate the following to an AD filter and I am at my wits end as I completely do not know powershell, any help will be appreciated

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users and Groups,OU=11111,OU=STATE,DC=net,DC=ads,DC=state,DC=tn,DC=us" -Properties memberof |
    Select samaccountname, @{n='memberOf';e={$_.memberOf -join '; '}} |
    Export-Csv c:\test.csv
```

Comment: What do you mean by an 'AD Filter' ?

Comment: Do you mean an LDAP filter for querying all users? That would be `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))`